# i don't have sound on my nb505 toshiba

Tags: drivers, sound, 64-bit, alsa, realtek

**Hi i'm currently running Ubuntu (lubuntu)18.04 LTS 64bit version on my netbook, everything is fine, except that I can't install the realtek hd audio drivers from the web, when i try to compile in the "make step" appears the last lines goes like this:

**

```
/home/danilo/Downloads/Rt-Linux-HDaudio-5.18/alsa-driver-RTv5.18/alsa/acore/init.c:1022:40: error: passing argument 2 of ‘remove_wait_queue’ from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
  remove_wait_queue(&card->power_sleep, &wait);
                                        ^
In file included from ./include/linux/mmzone.h:10:0,
                 from ./include/linux/gfp.h:6,
                 from ./include/linux/umh.h:4,
                 from ./include/linux/kmod.h:22,
                 from ./include/linux/module.h:13,
                 from /home/danilo/Downloads/Rt-Linux-HDaudio-5.18/alsa-driver-RTv5.18/alsa/include/adriver.h:50,
                 from /home/danilo/Downloads/Rt-Linux-HDaudio-5.18/alsa-driver-RTv5.18/alsa/acore/init.c:2:
./include/linux/wait.h:152:13: note: expected ‘struct wait_queue_entry *’ but argument is of type ‘int *’
 extern void remove_wait_queue(struct wait_queue_head *wq_head, struct wait_queue_entry *wq_entry);
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:332: recipe for target '/home/danilo/Downloads/Rt-Linux-HDaudio-5.18/alsa-driver-RTv5.18/alsa/acore/init.o' failed
make[3]: *** [/home/danilo/Downloads/Rt-Linux-HDaudio-5.18/alsa-driver-RTv5.18/alsa/acore/init.o] Error 1
scripts/Makefile.build:606: recipe for target '/home/danilo/Downloads/Rt-Linux-HDaudio-5.18/alsa-driver-RTv5.18/alsa/acore' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/danilo/Downloads/Rt-Linux-HDaudio-5.18/alsa-driver-RTv5.18/alsa/acore] Error 2
Makefile:1552: recipe for target '_module_/home/danilo/Downloads/Rt-Linux-HDaudio-5.18/alsa-driver-RTv5.18/alsa' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/danilo/Downloads/Rt-Linux-HDaudio-5.18/alsa-driver-RTv5.18/alsa] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-20-generic'
Makefile:167: recipe for target 'compile' failed
make: *** [compile] Error 2
```

**Of course when i try to go to the make install step, I can't do either, can anyone tellme whats wrong in here?**